# Fastest way to store HTTP session data?

Tags: database, performance, http, filesystems

I'm looking for the fastest way to store & read data associated with a HTTP session cookie.

Right now, we have a directory full of files, the filename is the session cookie (random ~150 characters) and the contents is a binary blob, usually only a few bytes - or sometimes as much as 1 or 2 kilobytes. We also use the atime (last read timestamp) to find and delete old session data.

This number of files in the directory can spike to millions, and the server is constantly checking if a file exists, what it's atime is, reading/writing them, and of course deleting/creating them. I suspect ext3 isn't the ideal approach to this usage pattern?

What is the best way to store this kind of data? We tested MySQL but it is orders of magnitude slower than ext3 (I assume we didn't do anything wrong?). Even just establishing a connection takes longer than performing a typical filesystem exists/atime/fread cycle.

Anyone with experience would be appreciated. What is the fastest way to manage a huge database of small unrelated pieces of data?

We are using PHP, with CentOS on high end server hardware (almost the best money can buy). There is no need for clustering/load balancing, we are trying to reduce per-request latency on mid-to-low traffic websites. We are not using PHP's built in session API, because it doesn't work in our situation.

Comment: Have you tried storing the session data as the cookie itself ?

Comment: @FrederickCheung My god you should never do that!

Comment: That's what rails does by default

Comment: @FrederickCheung every single request to your any URL at your domain name will include the cookie data, including image/css requests and even ones where the server sends an (almost) empty response telling the browser it's cached copy of the URL is up to date. And consumer grade internet connections have very slow upload speeds. So, it's critical to keep your cookies as small as possible. Having more than  a handful of bytes in the cookie is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 2):

Making the assumption your PHP is top notch and optimised, i would try changing the file system to ext4 (or should i say, creating an ext4 mount for the session data). ext3 is extremely slow by comparison so that could be your bottleneck.

ext2 would also be an option if you cant support ext4 (although ext4 has been out long enough now so you should be ok with it). However if you use ext2 make sure you have a separate mount just for the session data as it is unreliable and doesn't have journalling.

ext4 performs better on read than ext2, however ext2 performs better on writes ext4 (most likely down to its lack of journalling which creates "some" overhead, but that's my reasoning for it, i may be wrong).

**Edit:** I also thought it may be worth mentioning that smaller directories are better than one large one. However unless you are using a custom compiled kernel that increases the  32000 files per directory limit as default on ext3, your probably doing this anyway. But keeping the inode (the index of all files in the directory) small will increase performance. Something as simple as sorting files into directories based on their first x amount of characters could achieve this without adding too much processing overhead of finding the correct directory before being able to select the session file.

Comment: Thanks, I'll play with that. As far as I know, the 32000 limit (64000 on ext4) only applies to directories. You can have more than 10E19 files in a directory.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at an [in memory database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-memory_database)? They are fast as they don't need to touch the disk on each operation and some have options to write the data on disk once in a while to make it persistent also.

If your data is simple, a key-value store should be even faster as it is more lightweight, something like [Redis](http://redis.io/topics/introduction) for example or caching solutions with options to persist on disk (don't know for PHP but an example would be [EHcache](http://ehcache.org/) for Java).

Comment: I didn't know a memory database could save to disk, I'll look into that. We need to be able to reboot the server once or twice a year without killing everyone's session so I never considered it. Redis looks good too.

Comment: memcached would be another good option. Another benefit of any in memory db is that you can move the data store to another server if needed for better performance.